# Delete duplicate cells of a one column :html

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am to do the same as per This

```
<table id="test" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test3</td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>test4</td>
          <td>test2</td>
          <td>test5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test6</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test9</td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
              <td>test6</td>
              <td>test8</td>
              <td>test8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**LINK of Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shDpY/1/) 
I am able to delete the duplicates from table all columns,but I want to delete duplicate cell values from only first column.

### Orginal Output

[image]

### Remove duplicates from total table getting output as

[image]

### I want this

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Script**

```
var seen = {};
$('#test td:first-child').each(function() {
    // Encode column and content information.
    var key = $(this).text();
    if (seen[key]) {
        $(this).text('');
    }
    else {
        seen[key] = true;
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shDpY/16/)**

**Explanation:**

`$('#test td:first-child')` This helps to select only the first Row of the Table

Comment: `$(this).index()` is not necessary.

Comment: @dfsq yes edited, I just copied the SO user code and made the required changes actually

Comment: @dfsq another query i've is whether to use first-child or `this.index==0`

Comment: You removed key altogether. Should be `var key = $(this).text();`.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code it is working fine.

```
var seen = {};
$('#test td').each(function() {
    // Encode column and content information.
    var key = $(this).index() +  $(this).text();
    if (seen[key] && $(this).index()==0) {
        $(this).text('');
    }
    else {
        seen[key] = true;
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shDpY/18/)

Comment: but this might be an issue for larger tables not sure, if you can clear my doubt it will be great

Comment: $(this).index() will always return 0 first column. So, just added that condition also.

Comment: no that i understood i'm asking about which method is better out of the 2

Comment: just fyip confirmed firstchild is better :)