# Removing duplicate rows without checking the contents of the first column

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I have a table where the first column will always turn out to be unique. So when I remove the duplicate rows none would be removed. So i want to remove duplicates by eliminating the first row in the duplicate check. Each cell in the table may contain more than one value.

**Input Table**

[image: Input]

**Output table**

[image: Output]

I found the script for eliminating the duplicate rows from other question. But that is not what I am looking for. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26359016/5243291) question has something similar, but it is done only on the first column. I do not know how I can eliminate the first column from being accessed.

**Script**

```
<script>
  var seen = {};
  $('table tr').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (seen[txt])
      $(this).remove();
  else
    seen[txt] = true;
  });
</script>
```

**What I am trying to achieve**

I would first eliminate the duplicate elements within the cell and then eliminate the rows with duplicate values. So from the input table above, in the column C_fb 4000 being written twice would be eliminated and then checked for duplicate rows.

Comment: Your code actually works (http://jsfiddle.net/kjxL8rof/). How is the table created? Maybe you should attach this JS code on table load event. Or I may not understand the question...

Comment: @jolmos: yes the code works in the fiddle, but i have mentioned i do not want to check the first column. It is always distinct in my table so if i use my code none of the rows would be eliminated.

Comment: ah! Ok, I understood. So you just need to skip first column, Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kjxL8rof/2/

Comment: @jolmos: You got ir right for me :) Thanks a lot. Add it as an answer so that I can accept it. And is there a way to eliminate the duplicate item in the cell in the same script ?

Comment: @jolmos: the elements in the cell is a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combined [not selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [first selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), your code works!

```js
var seen = {};
$('table tr').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).find("td:not(:first)").text();
  
  if (seen[txt])
    $(this).remove();
  else
    seen[txt] = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>id1</td><td>aaaaa</td><td>ccccccccc</td></tr>
<tr><td>id2</td><td>bbbbb</td><td>dddddddd</td></tr>
<tr><td>id3</td><td>bbbbb</td><td>dddddddd</td></tr>
<tr><td>id4</td><td>bbbbb</td><td>dddddddd</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply the same on the list in the cell?

Comment: Yes it works with the list. But my approach is to remove the duplicate elements in the list and then remove the duplicate rows.

Comment: i did soemthing like this: but it removes all duplicate list items. it doesnt stay within the cell. http://jsfiddle.net/kjxL8rof/3/embedded/result/

Comment: Sorry for a wrong info. I have removed the list in the table. The elements are separated only by a new line :(

Comment: I have made an edit to your fiddle with the table that i have : http://jsfiddle.net/q5z789ry/1/. But since i made this change it isnt eliminating the duplicate rows but it works in my project

Comment: Well, it's not very elegant, but you can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/q5z789ry/2/

Comment: It works though. Why is it not elegant? What are the possible things that could go wrong in this case?

Comment: Well, I have nested 3 loops just to hide some information. I would try to do it when the data are fetched. Anyway, happy to help :)

Comment: I am also trying to eliminate the data in my controller rather than using scripts. i am in no way good at it. I never get the concept right. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: So i have found something where it doesnt add a new line. http://jsfiddle.net/q5z789ry/2/#&togetherjs=e9TGVtIJ8s. In this case I suppose i should replace string with new line rather than empty string. Or can it be done in another way?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:not` and the `:first` jQuery-Selector. source: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259393/jquery-select-all-except-first)

```
var seen = {};
$('table tr:not(:first)').each(function() {
var txt = $(this).text();
if (seen[txt])
  $(this).remove();
else
  seen[txt] = true;
});
```

Comment: thanks for the ans. But it isnt eliminating the duplicate rows. and i cant find the script in the browser debugger. I have added the scripts in the end of the file